# Debug runs into block with retain cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking, block

I have issue, I already known that can not be using that way, but all I want to ask here is just explanation, not how to fix. Please notice.

I'm using `UIImageView+AFNetworking`, i'm calling service like this:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {
        NSLog(@"In here.");
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
    }];
```

This case, it does not run into `NSLog(@"In here.")`. We can see `imageView` is released. But when I'm using like this:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {
        NSLog(@"In here.");
        imageView.image = image; /* I know this will make retain cycle. but don't care, just need explanation why? */
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
    }];
```

Now the debug runs into `NSLog(@"In here.")`, `imageView` someshow still retain, please some one tell my why?

**Notice:** Please don't give solution how to fix and correct way to use, just explain why?

=====

Thanks for all your supports, I finally get that.

In the first snippet code, `imageView` will `release` at the end of `setImageWithURLRequest`, so it will not call `success` block, and that is why `NSLog(@"In here.")` is not called.

In the second one, by setting `imageView.image = image`, will make retain cycle, that means `imageView` now is holding a strong reference to `success` block, and then inside the block, I'm calling `imageView` to use, so now the `success` block is holding a strong reference to `imageView`, that makes retain cycle and now `imageView` will not be released. Therefor, reaching into `NSLog(@"In here.")`.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. "Now the debug runs into In here, please some one tell my why?" Do you mean "why does the debugger get to the "In here" `NSLog()` line?

Comment: yes, exactly, it's easy to know. But let's me edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your code looks like this and runs under ARC

```
- (void) yourMethod {
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {
        NSLog(@"In here.");
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
    }];
}
```

Under ARC, `imageView` gets deallocated when control reaches the end of `yourMethod`.

By adding:

```
imageView.image = image;
```

the `success` block keeps a reference to `imageView`, and this is why you see the "In here" message (`imageView` will get deallocated at the end of `success` block execution). Try declaring `imageView` as a strong property of your class and you should get "In here" without adding this line to the `success` block.

Comment: Not fully but base on your idea, I have had my answer, thanks a lot.